# Can't Enter Trap Door in Zork

Tags: zork

At the beginning of the game of Zork there is a Trap Door. I try to Enter by Saying "Enter Trap Door" However when I do that it says "There is a Wall There".

I am playing Release 13

Comment: Try "open trap door" and then "down"?  The earliest text games weren't known for interpreting all commands equally.

Comment: @Radhil - Make that an answer!  Looks like it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest text adventures weren't known for their large language base or interpretation skills.  Many times if a specific door or object needs to be moved through, you need to supply a direction.

As in comments, "down" should work here.

Just for comparison, I appear to have Revision 88 in my library, and this specifically states as an error message, "You should supply a direction!" rather than what you get in your revision.

Comment: "The earliest text adventures weren't known for their large language base or interpretation skills." In general, Zork was the first where this was _not_ the case.

Comment: @MarkHurd - true, but Zork is more like the first point where the parser was quite usable.  It still had a lot more evolving and polishing to do before it stopped being a (major) obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but make sure that you MOVE the rug. If you just look under the rug and don't move it, you won't be able to open the trap door.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to *move* the rug, like Chris said. Then, you would say, *OPEN* the trap door, not enter!